# Knitr/R Markdown Privacy

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

If I create a Knitr document or use the R Markdown tool in R, will it be considered private? I have confidential data but want to make a report with it. The whole purpose is for me to send out multiple dygraphs on one page and from what I have read, it is one of the few options to do this.

Comment: Define "private". If you use the encapsulated format (i.e. everything base64 encoded and within the document) then no web bugs or web requests will go out, but the data will be transparent to anyone looking at the HTML.

Comment: Is the worry that you are starting with a data frame (say) that contains confidential data, and are using knitr to create anonymized views of the data, and are worried that from the pdf/tex output, someone would be able to recover the original data frame?

Comment: Well my goal is to create an html document/report (knitr) and email it to coworkers. Would somebody who is not on that email list be able to obtain it from the internet? @user295691

Comment: that is not a question about knitr, then, this is about emails and privacy, and may be more suited for http://security.stackexchange.com/